# Make a random forest estimator the exact same of a decision tree

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, decision-trees, cart

The idea is to make one of the trees of a Random Forest, to be built exactly equal to a Decision Tree.

First, we load all libraries, fit a decision tree and plot it.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
%matplotlib inline
import random
from pprint import pprint
import pdb
random.seed(0)
np.random.seed(0)
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

data = load_iris()

dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)
dtc.fit(data['data'].squeeze(),data.target)

tree.plot_tree(dtc)
```

[image: Decision Tree]

We then do the same thing with the random forest

```py
rf  = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1,max_features=None,random_state=0)
rf.fit(data['data'].squeeze(),data.target)
tree.plot_tree(rf.estimators_[0])
```

[image: Tree of Random Forest]

My question:

**Is it possible to make the exact same the first tree of the random forest and a decision tree?**

Comment: For a start, you'll need to set `bootsrap=False`.  But stripping our all the randomness so that the first tree is the same as DTC, you'll end up with _all_ the trees being the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `bootstrap=False` in the random forest to disable the subsampling.  (I originally commented because I expected there to be more impediments [in addition to your already-coded `random_state`s and `max_features=None`], but I guess there aren't any!)

You probably don't want to do this in general; by stripping out all the randomness so that the first tree is the same as the DecisionTreeClassifier, you'll end up with *all* the trees being the same, and the random forest loses its usefulness.