# Which decision tree model is used in "standard" random forest?

Tags: random-forest, decision-trees

Is that CART? Why not using C5.0 tree?

A perhaps more general question:

Since C5.0 tree frequently have better performance than CART, why people still use CART to build random forest (or people already are doing this)?

Comment: I suspect primarily this is because CART has always been open-source, while C5.0 started out largely proprietary.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/9979461/10495893

Answer (score 2):

My experience is with sklearn and python.

A Random Forest is a bagging of decision trees, the sklearn package uses [a Decision Tree Classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier) which is a CART.

You can see in [this post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/66891/make-a-random-forest-estimator-the-exact-same-of-a-decision-tree) that I made a bit ago of how to build a Random Forest tree the exact same as a decision tree.